# CSS flex make block exactly a 3rd

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a demo [here](https://codepen.io/ttmt/pen/wvyGrOM)

It's a simple css layout using flex to create a grid of 6 block, 3 across.

I'm using `flex: 0 0 33%;` to make the blocks a3rd of the width but there is slight space on the right side doing this.

If I try `flex: 0 0 33.33333%;` it makes the blocks 2 across.

Is it possible to have the blocks exactly 3 across

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex: 1 0 33%;` to allow the children to *grow* to fill the slight space between the elements:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Using `flex: 0 1 33.34%` will have the same effect, BTW, this time allowing the children to *shrink* from a slighly too wide width. Also note that I used `box-sizing: border-box` in both cases to *include* the border width in the calculated element width:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 1 33.34%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted the answer. The emphasis for _flexbox_ is in the _flex_ part. Setting `flex-grow` to `0` (i.e. the first `0` in `flex: 0 0 33%;`) is effectively stopping the flex child elements from flexibly grow.

Comment: Another suggestion for OP would be considering `grid` layout instead. This kind of grid-like structure is an excellent candidate for grid layout, in which you could set `0px` gap and `1fr` column width.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `border` (well - the 1px width of your border) property that is adding an additional `2px` inline to every `.block`.

You can avoid this by using `box-sizing: border-box` with the `33.33%` width value. The box sizing is set to `content-box` in the default user agent CSS, which means that properties like `border-width` and `padding` will add to the size of the box, whereas `border-box` sets the size first and then add the `border-width` and `padding` inside the dimensions of your box.

You can read more about `box-sizing` on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```